# Capture the stream from microphone in WAV formatting

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I'm migrating an metro style application from windows phone 7.5 to windows 8. My application was used to capture the microphone input stream .

I've found [MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) class in the win 8 api for metro style apps, but I see no possibililty to get the microphone input stream in wav encoding.

Switching to another encoding format would significally affect the codebase.

Is there any possibility to capture the microphone stream in wav encoding?

Comment: sorry for the missing details. hoped that the tags would bring clearness. question is updated.

Comment: By WAV, do you mean PCM? Or do you mean a streaming WAV?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. I recommend you to use Naudio class, and under sources you can easily find how to capture record.
Here is the code [EXAMPLE](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/)

Enjoy!

Comment: That example isn't a Metro style application.